# Разделить Dataframe на равные отрезки в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Как осуществить разделение DataFrame из 1000 элементов в цикле for на 10 отрезков по 100 строк каждый?
Пытался сделать таким способом, но в результате получаю 10 первых отрезка:

```
for index in range(100,1100, 100):
    df2 = df.iloc[:index]
    X = dosomething(df)
    print(X)
```

Или есть более простой способ это сделать?

Comment: Как-то странно вы делите, переприсваивая исходный датафрейм.

Comment: Вы правы. Изменил строчку так:  ` df2 = df.iloc[:index] `, теперь получаются отрезки 0 100, 0 200 и т.д.. Сейчас попробую придумать как получить 0 100, 101 200...

Comment: вы для каждого нового куска датафрейма указываете только верхнюю границу. в вашем случае нужно что-то типа такого: `df2 = df.iloc[index-100:index]`

Comment: То что надо! Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

chunks = np.array_split(df, 10)

for chunk in chunks:
    do_something(chunk)
```

Comment: А без pandas, с помощью pop?)